# Read an retrieve json file without adding wrap in laravel 7

Tags: json, laravel

I have a function that I want to read data from a json file and return them as they saved in file.

```
function getTimezones()
{
    $timezones = public_path('timezones.json');
    $tmp = json_decode(file_get_contents($timezones), true);
    return $tmp;
}
```

The `timezones.json` file data is like this:

```
[
    {
        "value": "Africa/Abidjan",
        "text": "Africa/Abidjan"
    },
    {
        "value": "Africa/Accra",
        "text": "Africa/Accra"
    },
    {
        "value": "Africa/Algiers",
        "text": "Africa/Algiers"
    }
]
```

But when data returns, it's wrapping with file name. Like this:

```
{
    "timezones": [
        {
            "value": "Africa/Abidjan",
            "text": "Africa/Abidjan"
        },
        {
            "value": "Africa/Accra",
            "text": "Africa/Accra"
        },
        {
            "value": "Africa/Algiers",
            "text": "Africa/Algiers"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the exact data of json file without `timezones` wrapper.

Comment: Are you returning `$tmp` or `new TimezonesResource($tmp)` ?

Comment: This code doesn't return any JSON.

Comment: What the output you want?